# vba code to find dates and display in another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, that isn't quite doing what I want it to

```
Sub returnDates()
    Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
    StartD = Cells(5, 3)
    EndD = Cells(6, 3)
    For Row = 1 To (EndD - StartD)
        Sheet3.Cells(Row, 3) = StartD + Row - 1

    Next Row
End Sub
```

At the moment it looks for the start and end date on another worksheet. it then returns the dates in-between. At the moment though it doesn't display the start and end date just the ones in-between. I am also having problems specifying the exact cell I want the dates to appear. I am wanting first date to appear in B2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub returnDates()
    Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
    StartD = Cells(5, 3)
    EndD = Cells(6, 3)
    For Row = 0 To (EndD - StartD) + 1
         Sheet3.Cells(Row + 2, 2) = StartD + Row 
    Next Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have declared the worksheets to work with and added some comments.

```
Sub returnDates()
    Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
    Dim lRow As Long

    'Create the worksheet objects
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    'Get the start and end.
    StartD = ws.Range("C5")
    EndD = ws.Range("C6")

    'Loop through and put the dates on the target sheet
    For lRow = 1 To (EndD - StartD)
        wsTarget.Range("C" & lRow) = StartD + lRow - 1
    Next lRow

    'Put the end date on the target sheet.
    wsTarget.Range("C" & lRow) = EndD
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code at the moment does show the start date but not the end date. I added + 1 to your For loop so that it will get that end date. I have changed you code to put the dates starting from B2 as you specify above.

```
Sub returnDates()
Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
StartD = Cells(5, 3)
EndD = Cells(6, 3)
For Row = 1 To (EndD - StartD) + 1
    Sheet3.Cells(Row + 1, 2) = StartD + Row - 1
Next Row
End Sub
```

Please note that technically it is bad practice to use a variable without dimension / declaring it. You are using Row which is probably a reserved name which is why it doesn't complain. Also note that sheet3 is assumed as the active sheet if you want to use another sheet let me know and I will modify to accommodate it.